# Angular2 search bar not working on mobile

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular2 front end (in a .Net backend) has a couple of search bars to filter an object array. It is working properly on a desktop, and even when changing the device to mobile in DevTools. However, when I publish my app and try to use the search bar on my phone, it does not work, and the array just disappears in the view.

My HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
<button class="btn btn-fs-orange btn-sm p-1 m-2" (click)="searchNames()">Search</button>
```

My typescript:

```
searchTerm: string;

searchValues: SearchValue[];
allSeearchValues: SearchValue[];

searchNames(){
        let value = this.searchTerm;
        this.searchValues = this.allSearchValues.filter((val) => val.searchName.toLowerCase().includes(value));
    }
```

I had originally had the function triggered by (input) and then tried (keyup), but neither worked. I then thought the search button would do the trick, but it still does not work. I'm particularly frustrated, as I have to publish my app before I can test if a change works.

Comment: In HTML you are calling `searchPlayers()` and in Typescript your function is `searchNames()`. `value` in `searchNames` should also be modified to lower case.

Comment: Just noticed that and fixed it. I changed some of the variable names when posting here to be less confusing.

Comment: Thanks Danilo, adding .toLowerCase() did the trick! I'm not sure why it works on desktop and not mobile - just browser differences?

Comment: I do not understand why it was working on desktop... :-)

Answer (score 1):

In my function, I was missing .toLowerCase() on the value from the search bar. It's now:

```
this.searchValues = this.allSearchValues.filter((val) => val.searchName.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
```